# Add multi selected items in listbox with multi column to an Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I am trying to add all selected items from a multi column listbox on a userform, to  my Excel worksheet. These are the codes I'm currently using:

```
Dim lrow As Range
Dim wst As Worksheet
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim lr As ListRow

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim xRow As Integer, intItem As Integer

Set wst = Sheets("TRAININGS PROFILE")
wst.Activate
wst.Range("B4").Select

For intItem = 0 To listbox1.ListCount - 1
If listbox1.Selected(intItem) = True Then

Set lo = wst.ListObjects(1)
Set lr = lo.ListRows.Add

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0)
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 1)
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
Next intItem

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This code works but the problem is it is only saving the last selected item from my listbox, it does not loop through each selected item. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change to code below:
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.ListBox1.List(intItem , 0)
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Me.ListBox1.List(intItem, 1)

Comment: Works like a charm! Now I'll just set it up so that every time I add new data, it will first locate the last row before adding. Thank you!